# How to specify additional CSOM properties to load in a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, client-object-model

In a PowerShell script, I'd like to retrieve the url of the content type hub tied to a site collection.

My scripts muse use the CSOM.

I tried :

```
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("http://myserver/mysite")
$MMS = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::GetTaxonomySession($Context)
$Context.Load($MMS)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

$termStore = $MMS.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore()
$Context.Load($termStore)

$Context.ExecuteQuery()

$termStore.ContentTypePublishingHub
```

This code does not throw any error, but does **not** output anything.

The server side equivalent code **does** output the hub url:

```
$session = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($site)
$session.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore.ContentTypePublishingHub.OriginalString
```

How to retrieve this url is CSOM ?

I suspect I should specify the `ContentTypePublishingHub` property in the  `Load` method, but I didn't found the syntax to specify additional properties to load. None of this worked :

```
$Context.Load($termStore, "ContentTypePublishingHub")
$Context.Load($termStore, $termStore.ContentTypePublishingHub)
$Context.Load($termStore, {param($ts) $ts.ContentTypePublishingHub })
$Context.Load($termStore, @({param($ts) $ts.ContentTypePublishingHub }))
```

**[Edit]** I tried the same code using C#:

```
var Context = new ClientContext("http://myserver/mysite");
var MMS = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(Context);
Context.Load(MMS);
Context.ExecuteQuery();

var termStore = MMS.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
Context.Load(termStore);

Context.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine(termStore.ContentTypePublishingHub);
```

This code throws a `PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException`. If change the load method to :

```
 Context.Load(termStore, ts=>ts.ContentTypePublishingHub);
```

The code outputs the expected urls.

This is an evidence for me, that the PS code does not specify property to load properly.

Comment: I know this sounds really basic but have you made sure the $MMS object is actually being instantiated properly by checking it's other objects and properties?

Comment: Again this might seem like a basic thing to point out but in SOM you're using $session.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore.ContentTypePublishingHub.OriginalString to get the URL, but in CSOM you're only using $termStore.ContentTypePublishingHub, so maybe you just need to add the OriginalString property onto the end of the CSOM command?

Comment: @ThomasGass: `ContentTypePublishingHub` property is present (but empty) in the $termstore object, and is a string.

Comment: That doesn't seem right - surely ContentTypePublishingHub should be an object, with OriginalString holding the string value? Or is OriginalString a generic method/property (I've not seen it before or had to use the CTH in a script).